# Using temporary threads in a long-running app?

Tags: python

I have a Python app that runs a pinball machine. It needs to run at a fairly consistent loop rate to do pinball-type things, but I also need to be able to load images and sounds at various points throughout the games. I don't have enough memory to pre-load all the sound files I need for the entire game, so I want to use an additional thread (or threads) to load them in the background while the main game loop continues on.

Using Python's `threading` module is easy enough, as is using a `Queue.Queue` to maintain a list of assets that need to load. My question is whether it's "ok" (for lack of a better word) to have the asset loader thread always running, or whether I should just create the thread when I need it and then let it end when I'm done. In my case the pinball machine—and my Python app—will be on an running for many hours (or days) at a time.

All of the examples of Python threading I've found tend to be for apps that do something and then end, versus creating (potentially) temporary threads for a long-running app.

In my case I think I have two options:

Option 1, where the loader thread runs forever:

```
self.loader_queue = Queue.Queue

def loader_thread(self):
    while True:
        do_my_work(self.loader_queue.get())
```

Option 2, where the loader thread ends when the queue is empty:

```
def loader_thread(self):
    while not self.loader_queue.empty():
        do_my_work(self.loader_queue.get())
```

Obviously I've left some things out.. Some `try:` blocks and a method for creating the thread in Option 2, but I think these snippets explain my two options.

The real question I have is that with Option 1, is that "bad" because then I'm wasting half of Python's execution cycles while the loader thread just spins and does nothing for the 99.99% of the time the queue is empty?

Or is this a case where I should use the first option, but use `self.loader_queue.get(block=True)`? I assume if my loader thread is just blocking while waiting for an item in the Queue then that's an efficient type of wait and I won't be wasting a bunch of cycles?

Thanks!
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default for [`Queue.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get) is to block, which is what you need:

> Remove and return an item from the queue. If optional args block is true and timeout is None (**the default**), block if necessary until an item is available. If timeout is a positive number, it blocks at most timeout seconds and raises the Empty exception if no item was available within that time. Otherwise (block is false), return an item if one is immediately available, else raise the Empty exception (timeout is ignored in that case).

This way the while loop only runs a single time for each item in the queue and is blocked when the queue is empty.

You can actually test this yourself by doing something visible (like printing some output) in the while loop.

Option 1 is good if you are waiting for items, since option 2 may terminate before you get them (if loader is fast enough).

The thread is probably not taking up enough resources to be considered as an optimization candidate. And since you're blocking it when it shouldn't be running option 1 seems to be the way to go.